# Outdoor ethernet to connect two sides of a building

Tags: ethernet

I have a modem and router on one side of a building. I want to string ethernet from my router, out through a window, along the outside of the building, and through another window in another room.

Do I have to get a special ethernet cord or surge protection?

The distance of the ethernet cable is no more than 150 feet and will not be a heavily used line with most of the time only 3 to 5 clients. The setup will only be used for a year or two so it does not have to withstand the outside elements for a long period.

The outside climate is rather temperate, being in central California. Temperatures go no lower than 35°F at night (but usually closer to 45°F) and as high as 110°F. We do not need to worry about snow, ice, or a lot of humidity, only the occasional rain.

So I believe that a normal Cat5 or Cat5e would be suitable, but there are special weather-proof cables with extra shielding. Do I need that or is it overkill?

Do I need some sort of surge protector to avoid damage to my router?

Comment: This is for your... house????  No business in their right mind should run cable out a window

Comment: That is an insane thing to do.  Standard, registered UTP cabling will not work outdoors. Sunlight, water, etc. will damage the cable. Please contact a cable professional for realistic implementations.  I wouldn't consider anything other than buried (minimum 24" to to top of cable) outdoor-rated (gel-filled, loose-tube, armored) fiber, using a proper cable pathway into and out from the building.

Comment: Wireless comes to mind.

Comment: As much as I've upvoted your comment Mike, I have seen "solutions" for small businesses along these lines. This is exactly the kind of crap that had me researching outdoor rated weatherproof cables. In DC we have historic buildings where typical wiring practices are illegal. That said, feels like an apartment or dorm to me also in this case.

Comment: Folks, this is off-topic, since the [OP is doing this in his apartment](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17809/outdoor-ethernet-to-connect-two-sides-of-a-building#comment26362_17813)

Comment: Yes it is technically off-topic but it definitely exists in the database so in that sense it is useful.  I have three networks in my home, and they are engineered precisely into separate subnets for separate functions.  It is quite possible to do professional work at home, especially when your home is your office.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who has done lots of crazy things to get equipment installed on ships at sea: I wouldn't quite call it insane.  Improper, yes.  Completely crazy (for a temporary solution), no.

I have a long run of [Ubiquiti Toughcable](https://www.ubnt.com/accessories/toughcable/) going from a wiring closet, through a conduit and waterproof gland onto my company's rooftop which connects to a microwave radio link.  It's been in place for nearly three years without any issues.  I think I am using the Toughcable Pro - no braiding.

A surge protector isn't going to help you here, but it would be wise to ground equipment well at both ends, if applicable.

But I must ask, why not run the link through your building?  Even if you have brick walls in the way or something, it still seems like it'll be easier and maybe quicker in the end.

Comment: Actually, running normal cable, as the OP suggests, is rather crazy. Outdoor rated cable must be bonded and grounded, and, per the National Fire Code, can't extend more than 50' into the building. There is a lot more to consider, and running normal cable into and out of a window is actually insane. Also, when people start talking about a year being temporary, you know it will become permanent.

Comment: Hence the recommendation for Ubiquiti Toughcable.  And the OP didn't ask us to speculate about how long he or she would leave it in place, they asked us "Do I need [outdoor-rated cable] or is it overkill?"

Comment: The OP said, "a year or two," not very temporary.

Comment: That's pretty subjective, isn't it? I'm just trying to be helpful to the OP by relating my success doing essentially the same thing, albeit with proper cable and not out a window.

Comment: The OP specifically asked if normal Cat5 or Cat5E cable running out a window for one to two years was suitable, or if something more is required. Something more is required, and you didn't directly answer the question. My comments were about the use of normal cable for this application. Your comment that that the OP didn't ask us to speculate about how long this would be in place leads me to believe you didn't completely read or understand the question. There are laws and regulations that need to be observed, and professional advice may prevent a red tag on the building.

Comment: Tedwin I upvoted this answer but I also definitely keep an eye on building and fire codes as they pertain to wiring because it's part of the job. It's also the right thing to do. Codes are almost entirely safety related. You don't want to have to try to sleep at night after one of your crazy wiring solutions gets someone hurt. Assuming the op is going forward, looking at outdoor cabke and correct grounding is a good place to start, hence the upvote. Better to get an experienced wiring contractor to devise the solution with their expertise though.

Comment: I am doing this in a small apartment building that I won't be living in for more than two years and I don't really have the ability to make holes or rewire anything. From what I gathered, people often have normal ethernet cords going outside and have them work for years but it does break building code and present safety hazards. So something could go wrong, but often doesn't. I know that is not a good reason to do it that way, that is just what I have concluded from what I have been reading.